# Python Regex - Matching tokens in different lines of a file

Tags: python, regex

In a file, I have the following lines:

```
[Line 1] My Name is Adam;
[Line 2] <Blank Line>
[Line 3] My Name 
[Line 4] is Adam Lee;
[Line 5] <Blank Line>
[Line 6] My
[Line 7] Name
[Line 8] is
[Line 9] Adam
[Line 10] Lee;
```

My tokens are: 'My' 'Name' 'Adam' and I know that they would end with ';'

Here is how I have written my code in Python:

```
#Read the input file
try:
    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    content = "".join(open(file_path))
    my_file = open(file_path).read()
except Exception as err:
    print("Exception caught while opening the file!")
    print(repr(err))
    exit()

# Find matches 
my_regex = r"^[ ]*My\s+Name.*Adam.*[;/]"
matches = re.findall(my_regex, my_file, flags=re.IGNORECASE + re.MULTILINE)
```

Observation:
Only Line 1 is getting matched. My expectation is Line 3-4 and Line 6-10 also get matched since the tokens and the delimiter ticks the boxes. How can I modify my regex? Please help.

Comment: can you write what string are you exactly expecting to get as out put? like : `My Name is Adam;` and `My Name \n is \nAdam Lee;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might write the pattern using a negated character class matching any char except a semicolon:

```
^ *My\s+Name[^;]*Adam[^;]*;
```

- `^` Start of string
- `*` Match optional spaces
- `My\s+Name` Match My Name with 1+ whitespace chars in between
- `[^;]*Adam[^;]*` Match Adam between optional chars other than `;`
- `;` Match the `;` at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0OE5sB/1)